# SubQuery<Date> can't group by in Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Hi I have a problem  using `groupBy`  with `subQuery` 
DB result

```
_______________________
|  id  |  departure   |
|______|______________|
| 99   |   00:54      |
|______|______________|
| 100  |   00:54      |
|______|______________|
```

I need

```
|  id  |  departure   |
|______|______________|
| 99 or|   00:54      |
|_100__|______________|
```

I using group by

```
public List<TripSchedule> findByDay(Date dateTime, Integer day, Long trainId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TripSchedule> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(TripSchedule.class);

    Root<TripSchedule> root = criteriaQuery.from(TripSchedule.class);
    Join<TripSchedule, Train> trains = root.join(TripSchedule_.trains, JoinType.LEFT);

    Expression<Date> departure = root.get(TripSchedule_.departure);
    Subquery<Date> subQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Date.class);

    criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);
    Root<TripSchedule> dateRoot = subQuery.from(TripSchedule.class);

    subQuery.select(departure).distinct(true);
    Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();

    if (dateTime != null) {
        predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(TripSchedule_.departure), dateTime));
    }

    if (trains != null) {
        predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.equal(trains.get(Train_.id), trainId));
    }

    if (day != null) {
        predicate = initPredicateByDay(root, predicate, builder, day);
    }

    subQuery.where(predicate);
    subQuery.groupBy(dateRoot.get(TripSchedule_.departure));
    criteriaQuery.select(root).where(builder.in(root.get(TripSchedule_.departure)).value(subQuery));
    TypedQuery<TripSchedule> tq = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return tq.getResultList();
    // return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

I don't know why predicate works fine but `groupBy` does't work.

Here is the generate sql:

```
select
    distinct tripschedu0_.id as id1_13_,
    tripschedu0_.name as name2_13_,
    tripschedu0_.departure as departur3_13_,
    tripschedu0_.friday as friday4_13_,
    tripschedu0_.monday as monday5_13_,
    tripschedu0_.period as period6_13_,
    tripschedu0_.saturday as saturday7_13_,
    tripschedu0_.sunday as sunday8_13_,
    tripschedu0_.thursday as thursday9_13_,
    tripschedu0_.tuesday as tuesday10_13_,
    tripschedu0_.wednesday as wednesd11_13_ 
from
    TripSchedule tripschedu0_ 
left outer join
    Train_TripSchedule trains1_ 
        on tripschedu0_.id=trains1_.SCHEDULE_ID 
left outer join
    Train train2_ 
        on trains1_.TRAIN_ID=train2_.id 
where
    tripschedu0_.departure in (
        select
            distinct tripschedu0_.departure 
        from
            TripSchedule tripschedu3_ 
        where
            1=1 
            and tripschedu0_.departure>=? 
            and train2_.id=5 
            and tripschedu0_.sunday=? 
        group by
            tripschedu3_.departure
    )
```

Comment: Nice formatting on the table, not so great on the code...  Can you make that a bit easier on the eyes?

Comment: Look into the generated SQL statement. Grouping is done based on a group/scalar/single-valued function(s) which does not appear to be applied to your case.

Comment: "It doesn't work". So *what* doesn't work? As said above, look at the generated SQL

Comment: Yes this forrmating is much better. Next time I will try use formatting like yours. Here is my sql after invoking a method [sql] (http://paste.ofcode.org/g33BFXw9BvBUuLpUJy4Pp3)